# What is a widget in Android?

Tags: android, widget

What is a widget in android?
Can I develop a widget for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can develop your own app for your application. But before you proceed please read through the link: [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

Answer (score 8):

See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A widget is an app that can update content on a home screen. It isn't just the size of one icon but can vary, taking up as much as one whole home screen if desired.

From Android 4.2 you can also have widgets on the lock screen.

The Google developer documentation is at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

There is also a good tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks. Am a noob around here and have just updated my answer.